# list all of the books that belong to a certain user android

Tags: java, android, mysql, queue, spring-tool-suite

i have this query on the server : "SELECT b FROM Book b WHERE b.user = ?1.
the user register a book in the plataform and the book gets them id and set it in the book table, but i'm not been able to make the same search in the interface.
in android i have this part:

```
  bookService.findByUser(book.getUsuario()).enqueue(new Callback<List<Book>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Book>> call, Response<List<Book>> response) {
            books.addAll(response.body());
            adapter = new BookAdapter(ListBooksActivity.this, books);
            mtBooks.setAdapter(adapter);
            mtBooks.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    book.setIdBook(books.get(i).getIdBook());
                    book.setTitle(books.get(i).getTitle());
                    book.setAutor(books.get(i).getAutor());
                    book.setGenre(books.get(i).getGenre());
                    book.setNumPag(books.get(i).getNumPag());
                    book.setDescription(books.get(i).getDescription());
                    book.setStatus(books.get(i).getStatus());
                    book.setUser(books.get(i).getUSer());

                    Intent itBooks = new Intent(ListBooksActivity.this, BookActivity.class);
                    itBooks.putExtra("user", user);
                    itBooks.putExtra("book", book);
                    startActivity(itBooks);
                }
            });
        }
```

the book service is:
@GET("/book/user/{idUser}")
Call<List> findByUser(@Path("idUser") User user);

please help

Comment: We could use more data regarding the issue that you are seeing with this query. Are you getting an error in the response? An empty response? Another type of error?

Comment: @Daniel i just solved this problem, but thanku